# What is the easiest way to find the scope of Lifehack site?

Tags: discussion, support

Sometimes when someone have off topic question and I want to send him a link to the page with Life-hack's scope, it is hard for me to find it. There is no link on visible place where everyone can check what is on/off topic. How can I easily find it, and can we add somewhere a visible link to the scope?

Comment: Similar: [Is the lack of a narrow scope problematic for this site?](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/1176/2272) and [The scope of Lifehacks](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/the-scope-of-lifehacks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, the scope would be [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center, but, as you probably know, we've been having trouble creating our scope. As of now, the best resource for finding out about what is on and off topic is [A Lifehacks Manifesto](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto?cb=1). In the manifesto, Robert Cartaino helps decide what is and isn't a lifehack. Hopefully we'll be able to put this scope in the Help Center soon. If you haven't gotten the chance you should definitely read it.

### Edit

The scope is now in the [Help Center](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It contains the information the Robert Cartaino posted a [A Lifehack Manifesto](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto?cb=1).

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered this particular SE site. It looks fun, but I do see an immediate issue in that I don't know how you'd create a scope for life hacks in general. Seems a lot of these questions could find homes on many of the other SE sites.

It feels much more like metafilter.

But maybe that's all OK. Perhaps this is the catch-all 'how do I do...' SE site for questions that don't fit anywhere else easily.

Comment: Actually the idea behind this site is not to be just 'how do I do...' SE site. It is for making something in an unusual way, something that is not the traditional way to resolve a problem. But mutch of the new users think the site is for giving the best ansver to a problem, no matter it is the normal solution which is wide used.

Comment: Yea, I get that it's really about how do I solve X but not using the most typical solution. Still, I think that's very much a 'how do I...' type of question. It's not a bad thing, just very broad.