# Are questions about doing something cheaper on topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

I was watching a show called [Hacking the System](http://channel.nationalgeographic.com/channel/hacking-the-system/series/hacking-the-system/) on Nat Geo and the episode that was on was about saving money. Almost all of the hacks in the episode would not be on-topic here, but the show still led me to wonder what Lifehacks.SE would think about hacks related to saving money. A question about doing something cheaper could be phrased like *How can I do {x} cheaper?* or *How to affordably do {x}* I'm not really sure if we should let these types of questions be on-topic or not, let me know what you guys think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straight from [the manifesto](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2431/15):

> seeking uncommon solutions to common problems

**IF** the question can reasonably be answered with an uncommon, inexpensive solution, I wholeheartedly believe it's on-topic.

Answer (score 6):

If it's a well formed question I don't see why not. Most of the questions asked have cheapness implied. If a person did ask "how to do it cheaper" it would be necessary to judge whether the question is good overall, not just cheapness. The questioner could be asked to reword, too, if necessary. Let's wait until we are overrun by cheapness questions then deal with it.