# Should a [cost-reduction] tag be created?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just reading this question regarding [Money saving questions being on topic](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2439/are-questions-about-doing-something-cheaper-on-topic) and general premise was:

> IF the question can reasonably be answered with an uncommon, inexpensive solution, I wholeheartedly believe it's on-topic.

So I was wondering if a [cost-reduction] tag or similar would be appropriate for these types of questions?
It would make it easier to identify questions asking about money saving solutions and therefore quicker to decide whether or not they are off topic as there are no unsuitable solutions or whatever.

While this tag would mean the asker is looking for cheaper alternatives, it may be the case that none are and naturally other answers simply to fix the issue should be accepted as good answers by the OP and possibly even lead them to having to edit the question in order to omit the cost cutting element of it.

Answer (score 4):

Would such a tag classify a question?

No, not really. All questions on this site are to some extent asking how to do things without spending too much money. This tag would not “identify questions asking about money saving solutions” [sic] — they all are.

“Looking for cheaper alternatives” is a matter of how the question is asked, not what answers the question is looking for. The same question without “here's a way to do it but it's too expensive” would call for the same answers, so it should have the same tag. Thus “cost reduction” is not a valid tag.

Thus, **no**, we should not have such a tag.

“Cost reduction” would be close to being a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/): it doesn't really classify questions, it's a subjective classification at best (since nobody wants to pay more, all questions want something cheap to some extent), and it can't serve as the sole tag on a question.

Answer (score -2):

Why not. I see no harm in adding a cost-reduction tag for those times when it's obvious this would be the effect. The ability to reduce cost is hackish.

Comment: New question. Is there a way to add a tag without having to create a question first?

Comment: @MrPhooky No, tags are created when you add them to a question (either when posting a new question or when editing an existing question).