# Are questions about legally questionable things on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

For example, if I were to ask:

> What is cheapest way to get the new [movie] that recently came out?

The possible answer would be to download it from a website using a certain software, even though that is illegal in my area.

I could also ask about doing things which are probably even more frowned on, but more life-hacky because its not a common solution (*where the problem is cost*)

> What is the cheapest possible way to get cable? Is it possible for me to turn on my cable for free, and how do I do it without special tools?

I'm sure there are other hacks that people may be able to come up with which are illegal, but could be considered a life-hack way to achieve a goal. Are these questions able to asked? Are we able to give a potentially illegal answer if the legal alternatives don't satisfy the goal as easily?

---

*I think there should obviously be some limit. [Are questions about doing something cheaper on topic?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2439/2093) - otherwise all these could be answered as, "find a way to steal it."*

Answer (score 5):

This is partially covered on a [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8492/202832):

> [A]s not all people on SE are from the same country and laws can be very diverse. I would comment on the answer that it breaks these [laws] in [country].

For Lifehacks, specifically, I encourage the downvote of answers that use thievery as a method. Flagging these as VLQ is also helpful.