# Dispute About Thread Closing

Tags: discussion, scope

This thread was closed:
https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/11725/fix-multi-page-web-articles

And I don't understand why. I took a look at the [Lifehacks Manifesto](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto), but that only served to convince me more that my question was valid.

> IF YOUR QUESTION IS ABOUT… 
> •> **seeking uncommon solutions to common problems**
> *asking for unusual ways of using everyday objects to make life easier*;
> •> **looking for simple and practical tips to life's everyday problems that may not have an obvious solution**

(emphasis mine)

> AND IT IS NOT ABOUT…
> •> **conventional "how to…" questions about skills that can commonly be learned elsewhere**
> •> **using products in the way they were designed to be used (e.g. keyboard shortcuts, obscure features, how to get your smartphone to do {x})**
> •> **"mind hacks" including personal productivity & self-improvement tips, memorization & learning techniques, etc**
> •> **contrived challenges that reject easy and readily available solutions simply to make the problem "more interesting"**

…then you are in the right place.

I touch on all of those bullets except one. It was mentioned in the comments that the site doesn't usually deal with digital issues, but why? That doesn't seem like a nearly valid enough reason to close an issue.

I didn't notice any other stack exchange child that would be more fitting (I could have missed it, I'm bad at finding things).

Given all of the above, I would like to move for my question to be reopened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I struggled with this one for a moment myself.

I'm almost certain there is no feature-supported way to solve your problem, so in the strictest sense, this would require a "hack." But **it's a *computer hack,* not a "life hack…"** at least in the sense of why we created this site.

A lot of computing and technical support is about coming up with *indirect* ways to solve these types of problems:

- How can I print out my calendar of today's activity automatically every morning?
- How do I download a YouTube video if I don't have YouTube Red?
- How can I transfer my old PC email to my new iPad pro?
- [How can I blank the computer screen if the kids get too noisy?](https://superuser.com/questions/545329/how-do-i-make-a-machine-blank-screen-for-a-period-of-time-as-a-penalty-if-ce)

The questions above would likely require really computer *hacky* answers, But I wouldn't want to see questions like these become part of *this* site. I just don't think they fit the use case for this site.

Comment: But as we move forward, do computers not become a more integrated part of our lives? At what point do we know when to blur the line or keep it clear? How much time of our lives do we all spend on the computer? Is improving that time, not improving our lives? You could argue that a car question is a "car hack, not a life hack", but there are also several on this site.

Comment: @goodguy5 That's playing a bit loose with the definition of this site. It's not a site about "anything that improves your life." There is no perfect word to describe this space precisely, so we control our scope by example and having these discussions. "Mind hacks" were disallowed under much the same premise—they simply got into an area outside the purpose of this site. I know that sounds a bit circular, but opening a can of worms to *"how to get my computer to do {x}"* is a different problem space... and I wouldn't want to see this scope of *this* site opened to everything that comes with it.

Comment: Fair enough. No computer stuff on the site at all. Got it... Any advice on where to go, then?

Comment: @goodguy5 I've had luck with [*similar* types of questions](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89342/prevent-browser-tab-from-playing-youtube-video-automatically) on WebApps, but I'm not sure if a generic website question would fit. Perhaps your question can be tailored to fit, or perhaps Super User. I'm not sure.