# How can I verify the weight of seafood when ordering takeaway from restaurants?

Tags: discussion

Why was [How can I verify the weight of seafood when ordering takeaway from restaurants?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/23441/1869) closed?

> [food - How can I verify the weight of seafood when ordering takeaway from restaurants? - Lifehacks Stack Exchange](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/23441/how-can-i-verify-the-weight-of-seafood-when-ordering-takeaway-from-restaurants?noredirect=1#comment35059_23441)
>
> - **This question doesn't seem to be about a problem.**
> - **Does not seem to need a life hack**

I'm uncertain how either close reason applies. I explained the problem quite manifestly, I think? I asked for a life hack other than bringing a scale to the restaurant.

Answer (score 5):

**How can I verify the weight of seafood when ordering takeaway from restaurants?**

This question is not genuinely about a life hack situation and as such is off topic here.

This question about weighing food does not satisfy our criteria of thinking outside the box!

> A "life hack" is generally a tool or technique used to solve an everyday problem in unexpected ways. We can't let this become a catch-all site where pretty much anything is on topic — but we are pretty comfortable with harnessing all the creative energies of our hacker-mindset culture to find those intriguing, unexpected solutions to the stubborn problems we face everyday!
>
> **So what is a life hack?**
>
> A life hack is a seemingly intractable, stubborn problem that can be solved by…
>
> …thinking "outside the box".
>
> [A Lifehacks Manifesto](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto)

However this question is quite possibly on topic on [Seasoned Advice SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restaurant).

Answer (score 3):

The topicality of questions on Lifehacks.SE is largely defined by the [Lifehacks Manifesto](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2431/6973) which was posted during the formation of the site.

The question about weighing food does not satisfy these criteria.
The advertised weight of meat in a restaurant menu refers to *uncooked* weight.
It does not require an "out of the box" solution to a problem.
If your food doesn't comply with the advertised standards, you complain to Trading Standards.
Also, your posting of a restaurant's contact details could be construed as spam.

Other questions regarding food have also been closed, for example:
[How to determine if expired food is still good without eating](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/10822/6973)
which has comments stating the same reasons as given here.